# Padding not working for my text

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<div id="main">
<div style="position: absolute; height: 150px; width: 400px; left: 290px;"><img src="HEAD-IMAGE.jpg" /></div>
<div style="position: absolute; height: 300px; width: 233px; top: 180px;"><img src="LEFT-IMAGE.jpg" />(below head)</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 270px;">TEXT (next to left image)</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div#main{
 position: absolute;
 top: 141px; left: 50%;
 height: 100%; width: 960px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-left: -490px;
 text-align: justify;
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

my padding from #main works for my images but not for my text (right & bottom padding).

Comment: Why all the inline styling?

Comment: Sure, `left: 0; top: 0;` is left top corner when you are using absolute positioning. Parent padding isn´t reflected.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve. Do you have a working sample so that we can check it and suggest.

Comment: @panther TY now I see that for absolute positioning parent padding is not reflected as you said. But why is it reflected on my images?

Comment: @Pavlos1316: I don´t know what you mean. There are no images, only 3 divs, are positioned absolutely and have no padding. Parent (#main) have padding, but no content. If you want to simulate paddings, add to each div to their `left` and `top` +10px, result will be as zou expected.

Comment: @panther My bad. I didn't put the image tag inside my divs. just the text.. In my first 2 divs I have images which were using my # main padding. But not the 3rd div that had the text in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is this happening?

In your example, only the text div has a `top` and `left` property. The two divs containing the images only contain one of these properties:

- The header div has `left: 290px;`, so it gets its y-axis position moved by the top padding.
- The left div has `top: 180px;` so it gets its x-axis position moved by the left padding.
- The text div has `top: 200px; left: 270px;` so its x and y-axis are not affected by the padding.

To illustrate this, for this example the text div has had its `left` property removed. It is now affected by the left padding of its container:

("Show code snippet" and run it)

```css
#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 141px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 960px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-left: -290px;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  left: 290px;
  background: #F00;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 233px;
  top: 180px;
  background: #F00;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">You can't handle the truth, soldier!</div>
</div>
```

### Is position: absolute the best way to layout my elements?

Depends... `position: absolute` removes elements from the normal flow of the document. That is, each element is essentially invisible to the other. This is particularly problematic if you wish to create a flexible layout, which can re-size in accordance with the users browser height / width.

### Can you show me another way to layout HTML elements?

Sure! There are many ways to layout a page **without** resorting to `position: absolute`. Here is a basic example using `display: flex` — a newer way to layout elements. It does not enjoy 100% browser support yet, so this is purely an example of one technique :)

Read more:

- about [`vw` and `vh` units on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)
- about flexbox over on CSS-Tricks - [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- about [flexbox browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

#### Flex example

Note how the elements resize when the example is made full-screen.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #424242;
}
header {
  background: #e91e63;
  height: 20vh;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  background: #fce4ec;
  flex: 1;
}
.content {
  background: #fafafa;
  min-height: 70vh;
  flex: 2;
}
footer {
  height: 10vh;
  background: #c51162;
}
```

```html
<header>
  I am header
</header>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
    I am sidebar
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    I am content
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  I am footer, hear me roar! RWAR!
</footer>
```

Comment: You haven't asked for further advice, but I updated my answer anyway if you are interested :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a class `.child` for your `<div>`

```
<div class="child">
```

and define style accordingly

```
.child { padding: 10px; }
```

Comment: I know that this is an option.. but I want to find out why my images are accepting my pading while my text doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative;` on the child divs to make them account for the parent divs padding.

Answer (score 0):

problem is you give left and top to text div that why not accept padding,simply remove left to text div then it will accept the  padding...

Comment: This would be more helpful if you included the code with changes as you describe.